# Static files(css,js) are not loading, node express angular project

Tags: node.js, express, ibm-cloud

I have a project which has been built using Node  js, Express framework and Angular js. I have deployed the project on Bluemix. When I hit the URL in browser the static content(css, js) is not being loaded. Browser says 404 Not found. 
Folder structure: Views-->index.ejs
                  !
                  !
                  Content--->style.css

Views and Content folders are at the same level.

I tried below paths.

```
<link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set up your static file middleware as per [Serving static files in express](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).  Have you set your view engine as per [Using template engines](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html)?

Comment: Does it work when you run locally?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you set the public directory for your files to be accessed by express. This is an example:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Then you need to reference your front-end files (css, img, etc.) in reference to this directory (so if you have a `public/img` folder, the reference url will be `<img src="img/NAMEOFIMAGE.jpg">`

Hope this helps. Comment below with any issues.

Thanks

Comment: Did this answer your question? Or are you having a different problem?